# Elementary proofs involving inequalities

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

So the task of this exercise is to prove each statement.

1. $\forall a \in$ $\mathbb R$: Prove that $a^2 \ge 0$

Does it suffice to say that $a^2 \gt 0$ or $a^2 = 0$, which means that $a \gt 0$ or $a \lt 0$, or $a= 0$?

2. $\forall a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$: $ a \lt b$ and $b \lt c$ $\Rightarrow$ $a \lt c$

Isn't this statement just self-explanatory?

3. $\forall a,b \in \mathbb R^{-}$: $a \lt b$ $\Rightarrow$ $a^2 \gt b^2$

I've written that if you multiply both sides with each other that the order reverses. Should that be enough?

4. $\forall a,b \in \mathbb R^{+}: a \lt b \Rightarrow a^{2} \lt b^{2}$

This is just the opposite of statement n°3. So the order remains because you multiplie both sides respectively with $a$ and $b$.

5. $\forall a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R: a \lt b$ and $ c \lt d \Rightarrow a + c \lt b + d$

I don't know how to prove this one but just like statement 2 I think this is just self-explanatory.

6. $\forall a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R: a \lt b$ and $ c \lt d \Rightarrow a-d \lt b-c $

Same with statements 2 and 5.

7. $\forall a,b \in \mathbb R_0^ {+}: a \lt b \Rightarrow a^{-1} \gt b^{-1}$

Here the reason why the order reverses is because of the fact that the absolute value of $b \gt a$ which means that if you take reciprocical $ \frac 1b \lt \frac 1a$

8. $\forall a,b \in \mathbb R_0^-: a \lt b \Rightarrow a^{-1} \gt b^{-1}$

Same idea as statement 7 but only with negative real numbers.

9. $\forall a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R^+: a \lt b$ and $ c\lt d \Rightarrow ac \lt bd$

Same with statements 2, 5 and 6.

10. $\forall a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R^-: a \lt b$ and $c\lt d \Rightarrow ac \gt bd$

The absolute value of both $a$ and $c \gt b$ and $d$ which causes the order to reverse.

Could someone give me hints how to "prove" statements 2,5, 6 and maybe fill the gaps in other statements?

Comment: I think it would be useful to know here what is your definition of 'negative number'. Are you taking the existence of $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ for granted and stating the definition of 'positive' and 'negative' in terms of this?

Comment: With $\mathbb R^+$ I mean the set of all positive real numbers and with $\mathbb R^-$ I mean the set of all negative real numbers.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It still isn't clear what that means exactly. I understand what you mean, of course, but you would still need a rigorous definition of $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ in order to give a rigorous proof of the above propositions.

Comment: But that's the only thing my coursebook mentions

Comment: How do you mean? What should such definition say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a rigorous proof based on axioms.

Let $\mathbb{R}^{+} \subset \mathbb{R}$ satisfying:

1. For $a \in \mathbb{R}$, exactly one of the following holds: $a \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$; $-a \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$; or $a = 0$ (The trichotomy law)
2. $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \Rightarrow a + b \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ (Closed under addition)
3. $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \Rightarrow ab \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ (Closed under multiplication)

(In these definitions, 'closure' means you stay within the set which both elements are taken from. For example, $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under multiplication since $a \times b \in \mathbb{Z}$ for any $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. But it is not closed under division, since $\frac{3}{4} \notin \mathbb{Z}$. If a set is not closed under some operation, it means you can 'get outside' the set using that operation on elements from the set.)

Then we may call $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ the positive numbers and say $a>0$ means $a \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$

Now, for something like your statement $`a \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow a^{2} > 0'$, we could give a rigorous proof case by case.

- $a = 0 \Rightarrow a^{2} = 0\times 0 = 0$
- $a \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \Rightarrow a\times a \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ by multiplicative closure
- $ -a \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \Rightarrow (-a) \times (-a) = a \times a \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, again by multiplicative closure.

For this third case, you will want to have a proof handy that $(-a) \times (-b) = a\times b$, of course!

These kinds of very fundamental proofs can seem a bit heavy handed at first, but really it is important to be detailed and rigorous or else more advanced mathematics is built on shaky foundations.

Additional example:

Prove that $a<b, c<d \Rightarrow a+c < b+d$

By definition, $b-a \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $d-c \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$. We have
 \begin{align*}
 & (b-a) + (d-c) \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \,\, \text{by closure} \\
 \Rightarrow & (b+d) - (a+c) \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \\
 \Rightarrow & b+d > a+c
 \end{align*}

Comment: Oh, yes I see now what I should do. I need to go over the relevant cases involving the terms.

Comment: For your second statement, we can extend the definitions so that $$b>a \Leftrightarrow b-a \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$$ and then try and use the axioms 1 to 3 in the answer to prove that $b-a \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $c-b \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ then $(b-a) + (c-b) = c-a \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ since $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ is closed under addition, as another example.

Comment: Yeah, of course just like the unity of addition and order as we call it in dutch (litteraly translated) .

Comment: And are the other statements except 5 and 6 complete or not?

Comment: So, I would say that all of the remaining statements 3. to 10. in your question need to be proved with specific reference to the axioms I mentioned in my answer, which means (to good standards of rigour) you need to redo all of the proofs in a stricter style. The things we call 'self explanatory' are called axioms and the aim is to have as few of these as possible and prove everything else from them. 

Could I suggest a great book? Calculus by Michael Spivak. The first chapter is very good on this subject.

Comment: Does closure mean without a doubt because you take something over from an axiom?

Comment: Ok, it is clear now